# iOS interface orientation changes inconsistent

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, viewwillappear

Using latest xCode and iOS 6 build target for app is 4.3
As an example my first view is a tableview of 8 rows.
User presses 8th row and it pushes the 2nd view which is also a tableView but of 4 rows.
User presses 4th row and it pushes a standard view NOT a tableView. sharedManager is my singleton that specifies the row height of the tableviews for either of the orientations and detected device i.e iPhone or iPad. The app is a universal app.

In all of these views I have the below in the viewWillAppear

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        //iPhone Portrait
        self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeight];

    }

    else{

        //iPad Portrait
        self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightIpad];
    }
    }

    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        //iPhone Landscape
        self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightLandscape];

    }

    else{

        //iPad Landscape
        self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightLandscape_iPad];


    }
  }
 }
```

and I also handle the same orientation change in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

```
  - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
  NSLog(@"willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: %d", toInterfaceOrientation);

  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    NSString *iPhoneOrientation;
    switch(toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            iPhoneOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightLandscape];
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            iPhoneOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightLandscape];
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            iPhoneOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeight];
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            iPhoneOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeight];
            break;

        default:
            iPhoneOrientation = @"Invalid orientation";
    }
    NSLog(@"willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: %@", iPhoneOrientation);

 }

 else{

    NSString *iPadOrientation;
    switch(toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            iPadOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightLandscape_iPad];
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            iPadOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightLandscape_iPad];
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            iPadOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightIpad];
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            iPadOrientation = @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown";
            self.tableView.rowHeight = [sharedManager contactRowHeightIpad];
            break;

        default:
            iPadOrientation = @"Invalid orientation";
    }
    NSLog(@"willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: %@", iPadOrientation);

 }

}
```

Now the issue I have is when going from view 1 - 3 in any of the orientations works fine however when I rotate say view 3 to landscape then go back to view 2 and 1 the rotation code is not working in landscape and is displayed incorrectly even though I specify the correct layout frame for all elements as is proven when going from view 1 - 3?

Also what may be helpful in determining the problem is that the first view I hide the navigation bar and unhide it in views 2 and 3. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: You should specify which iOS version you're targeting. iOS 6 works entirely different from iOS 5 (and iOS 6 seems to be a hair buggy as well).

Comment: @HotLicks I am using the latest xCode and iOS 6 but the build target is 4.3. I have read about using the enum iOS rotation masks however the should rotate methods are working correctly its coming back to a view rather than going to a view thats not working correctly if that makes sense.

Comment: That's one of the areas where iOS 6 seems to have trouble.  Dunno about prior versions.